# How can I customize the action icons in Material Table dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-table

I have a set of icons that I got from the [official docs](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table), and I'm wondering if there is a way to conditionally render different icons? For instance, my API returns an array of objects, which have a `deleted` property, and I'd like to render a `TrashIcon` if it is set to `false`, and a `RestoreFromTrashIcon` if it is set to `true`. I've tried customizing the `actions` property on the Material Table, setting the icon as,

```
actions={[
  {
    icon: (h) =>console.log("h", h) || "edit",
    tooltip: "Edit",
    onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You are editing")
  }
]}
```

But this just adds an extra icon to the two already-existing ones. That, and also `h` is just an object with a `disabled` property.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

The actions array accepts an Action object or a function containing the rowData as a parameter and returning a Action object. In your case it would be:

```
actions={[
  rowData => ({
    icon: rowData.deleted ? 'restore' : 'delete',
    tooltip: "Edit",
    onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You are editing")
  })
]}
```

You can check the documentation on GitHub since this example is not rendering in the documentation page: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table.com/blob/master/src/pages/docs/features/actions/conditional-actions.js